# Python: find all possible combinations between one array and N arrays

Tags: python, arrays

In Python, I am looking for a generic way (i.e. [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)) to build an `array` with all possible combinations between a given one dimensional array and N one dimensional arrays.

Here is a simplified example.

### Input

```
main = ["a1","a2","a3"]
secondary = [["b1","b2"],["c1","c2","c3"]]
```

### Expected output

```
[
  ["a1","b1","c1"],
  ["a1","b1","c2"],
  ["a1","b1","c3"],
  ["a1","b2","c1"],
  ["a1","b2","c2"],
  ["a1","b2","c3"],
  ["a2","b1","c1"],
  ["a2","b1","c2"],
  ["a2","b1","c3"],
  ....
  ["a3","b2","c3"]
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) like so:

```
from itertools import product

main = ["a1","a2","a3"]
secondary = [["b1","b2"],["c1","c2","c3"]]
[list(a) for a in product(main, *secondary)]
```

Output:

```
[['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
 ['a1', 'b1', 'c2'],
 ['a1', 'b1', 'c3'],
 ['a1', 'b2', 'c1'],
 ['a1', 'b2', 'c2'],
 ['a1', 'b2', 'c3'],
 ['a2', 'b1', 'c1'],
 ['a2', 'b1', 'c2'],
 ['a2', 'b1', 'c3'],
 ['a2', 'b2', 'c1'],
 ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'],
 ['a2', 'b2', 'c3'],
 ['a3', 'b1', 'c1'],
 ['a3', 'b1', 'c2'],
 ['a3', 'b1', 'c3'],
 ['a3', 'b2', 'c1'],
 ['a3', 'b2', 'c2'],
 ['a3', 'b2', 'c3']]
```

Comment: That was it, thank you.